Why does my FileSystemEventHandler only trigger once?
I am dealing with a frustrating problem. I am trying to use watchdog observers to monitor a list of hosts.
If a host is added, I want it to interrupt the loop and immediately ping the host and add the results to results.json.
If a host is removed, I want it to immediately remove the host and ping result from results.json.
This seems to somewhat work, but only once. Upon starting, it will loop through hosts.txt like normal and log the ping results. If the hosts.txt is modified, the handler will trigger and perform the appropriate action. However, after modifying the file once, it will no longer recognize any additional file modifications.
What am I doing wrong?
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import time
import logging
import json
import os
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

def get_hosts():
    with open("C:/dashboard/www/mysite/dashboard/hosts.txt", "r") as hosts_file:
        hosts = hosts_file.readlines()
    return [host.strip() for host in hosts if host.strip()]

def check_ping_and_log(hosts):
    global results  # Declare results as global to access the global variable
    dt = datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    for host in hosts:  # Ensure this loop iterates over the hosts list
        try:
            result = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-n", "2", host])
            result = result.decode("utf-8")
            lines = result.split("\n")
            for line in lines:
                if "Average" in line:
                    latency = line.split("=")[-1].strip()
                    latency = latency[:-2]
                    results[host] = latency
                    log_message = f"{host},{latency}ms"
                    logging.info(log_message)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            results[host] = "down"

        results = dict(sorted(results.items()))

        with open("C:/dashboard/www/mysite/dashboard/results.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(results, f)

class HostsFileChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    """Handles changes in the hosts file."""
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(event)
        if os.path.abspath(event.src_path) == os.path.abspath("C:/dashboard/www/mysite/dashboard/hosts.txt"):
            print("Hosts file modification detected")
            global hosts, results
            new_hosts = get_hosts()  # Load the new hosts list
            added_hosts = [host for host in new_hosts if host not in hosts]  # Identify newly added hosts
            removed_hosts=[host for host in hosts if host not in new_hosts] # Identify removed hosts
            if added_hosts:  # If there are newly added hosts
                check_ping_and_log(added_hosts)  # Ping only the newly added hosts
            if removed_hosts:  # If there are removed hosts
                for host in removed_hosts:
                    results.pop(host, None)
            hosts = new_hosts  # Update the global hosts list with the new list

def monitor_hosts():
    global hosts
    hosts = get_hosts()  # Initialize hosts list before entering the loop
    path = "C:/dashboard/www/mysite/dashboard"  # Directory to watch
    event_handler = HostsFileChangeHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            hosts = get_hosts()  # Update hosts list in each iteration to reflect any changes
            check_ping_and_log(hosts)
            time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()

logging.basicConfig(filename='C:/dashboard/www/mysite/dashboard/ping_logs.log', level=logging.INFO, 
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(message)s|', datefmt='%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S')

results = {}
hosts = get_hosts()
monitor_hosts()  # Call the function to start monitoring


If I have the event handler print all events, I can see all other file modification events normally. It will continue to report events as it should until the hosts.txt file is edited, then it stops reporting events.
